# Changing the data for hue in a scatterplot created by Seaborn relplot does not update the legend

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, relplot

I have five columns in a pandas dataframe **df**: 'axis_1', 'axis_2', 'axis_3', 'axis_4', and 'axis_5'.

I create a scatter plot using Seaborn's **relplot** function as follows:

```
grid = sns.relplot(data=df[[axis_1, axis_2, axis_3]], x=axis_1, y=axis_2, hue=axis_3)
```

The result is a scatter plot as follows

[image]

Now I use **map** to redraw the scatter plot so that it uses 'axis_4' instead of 'axis_1' column and 'axis_5' instead of 'axis_3' column. That is, I changed the data for X and for HUE.

```
grid.map(sns.scatterplot, x=df[axis_4], y=df[axis_2], hue=df[axis_5])
```

It works perfectly as far as the graph is concerned, i.e. the points have changed and so have their colors, according to the new data. The new plot is:

[image]

There is a problem, anyway: the legend. Both the title and the colors and values of the legend have remained the same as before. The **map** function did not update the legend, and it is not easy to do this by hand because **relplot** uses its own algorithm to determine what the hue-based legend looks like, and it would have to be reused.

Am I facing a limitation of the Seaborn library or is there some way to tell map to also regenerate the legend in the correct way?

Comment: `FacetGrid.map` doesn't change the legend. In general, it's rather hard for seaborn to guess how you'd want to combine the old and the new legend. Wouldn't it be easier to just create a new plot?  (Reusing a plot instead of recreating it doesn't have real benefits.)

Comment: Well, recreating the plot is quite time consuming. I found a workaround, anyway, that I describe in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution yet, but I found a workaround and I wish to share it here, in case it could be useful to someone else.

First I moved the legend created by Seaburn out of sight, that is, outside the Tkinter canvas, by

```
sns.move_legend(grid, "upper center", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 2))
```

Then I created a *mathplotlib* legend. It looks like that legend replicates the legend already created by Seaburn. Note that, if I remove the Seaburn legend rather than moving it out of sight, the resulting *mathplotlib* legend is empty. That is why I move the original legend rather than removing it.

```
    plt.legend(
        title=<<<dynamic value based on hue data>>>,
        loc='center right',
        bbox_to_anchor=(1.16, 0.5)
    )
```

When I change the data in the scatter plot, also the title of the legend changes and the legend changes according to new **hue** data. By magic. :-)

The resulting chart now is:

[image]